# How to filters record in a table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table  name 'deployment_status' with following column.
req_id , application_id ,location_id , status.
It is used to track what application are deployed  in which location and what`s their status.
I have attached screenshot of few records in a table. [image]

I want to write query which will tell the status of each location whether they have deployed all the applications or not.

We have following rules regarding status of each location

1. for a location  per request id  if any of the application deploy status is failed then consider it is 'failed'.
2. For a location per request id if all the application deploy status is complete then consider it is  'complete'
3. for any other case consider status as retry.

I am expecting following result set.

| req_id | location_id | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | Complete //since for request id 1 both applications 1 & 2 status is complete. |
| 1 | 1001 | Retry // application 1 status is CMP but application 2 status is INP |
| 1 | 1002 | Retry |
| 2 | 1000 | Retry |
| 3 | 1000 | FAIL |

My question is can we  achieve above result set using a single query.
I have tried few times with self join but not able to get desired result.
I will appreciate any help/guidance. Thanks.

Note: I am using oracle

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following does what you want. I'm not sure it's the best method, but it's readable to me.

```
SELECT req_id, location_id, CASE MAX(numstat) WHEN 2 THEN 'Fail' WHEN 0 THEN 'Complete' ELSE 'Retry' END status
FROM (
 SELECT req_id, location_id, CASE status WHEN 'FAIL' THEN 2 WHEN 'CMP' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END numstat
 FROM deployment_status)
GROUP BY req_id, location_id
ORDER BY req_id, location_id
```

The idea here is that the inner query assigns a numeric value for the status, which makes it easy to use `MAX` in the outer query. You could use strings instead of numbers, but you would still need to translate since you want to ensure FAIL is the highest possible value and CMP is the lowest possible value (or the opposite and then use `MIN` instead of `MAX`).

Once that's done, in the outer query

- If the `MAX` is 2/FAIL, then there must be at least one FAIL
- If the `MAX` is 0/CMP then all of them must be CMP
- Otherwise, there is a mix of non-FAIL (might or might not include a CMP, but they can't all be CMP)

Here's a [Fiddle of it working](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9068f0d2ea370c6f0b91b5e623868026).

The same basic idea using a window function instead of an inner query is the following.

```
SELECT DISTINCT req_id, location_id, CASE MAX(CASE status WHEN 'FAIL' THEN 2 WHEN 'CMP' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY req_id, location_id) WHEN 2 THEN 'Fail' WHEN 0 THEN 'Complete' ELSE 'Retry' END status
FROM deployment_status
ORDER BY req_id, location_id
```